# Relative Layout and removed Google Banner-Ad

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with an ad from admob. Everything works fine. But I let my users buy the ad away (remove ad with in-app buy). But when the Ad ist removed programaticaly (setting it invisible) the design "collapses". All elements are at the top of the screen stacked. Within the Ad there is a paramater:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

which seems to be the reason for this strange behavior when its removed.

How can I fix my layout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_activity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout>      
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView>


    <LinearLayout

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use visiblity : gone . visibility invisible just hide view but take up space in layout

Comment: Hi, I am already using the correct code mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE); its not a code isue, i need a layout hint why the missing "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"" causes the collapsing of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on my own: Put the Adsense-Ad within an additional Lin-Layout and made it stick to the bottom. When the Ad inside disapears, the Lin is still there, but empty.